# npm: How to reset the node_modules prefix

Tags: node.js, macos, configuration, npm, npm-install

i installed node via homebrew. 
Since i had problems accessing the packages, i tried to change the node_modules prefix to `user/local` but made an error while typing the command:

```
npm config set prefix /usr/l    # See the typo there
                            ^
```

Now, whenever i run an npm command i get the following error:

```
$ npm config ls -l
Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/l'
at Error (native)
```

i cannot set the prefix again (`npm config set prefix /usr/local`) , or even list the config ( `npm config ls -l` ) – all produce the same error as above.  I tried re-installing node/npm.

How do i reset the prefix? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a permissions error, you should be able to use sudo to run it as root. This should take care of permission problems, which it appears to be in the error message

Comment: `sudo npm config set prefix /usr/local` did the trick. Thanks.